Axios Error "entity.parse.failed" (When sending FormData)
I'm trying to make a request using Axios and I need to send body as a FormData but I'm getting this issue:
Axios Error:
{
  "errors": {
    "expose": true,
    "statusCode": 400,
    "status": 400,
    "body": "----------------------------524246740682154737031830\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"proposalData\"\r\n\r\n{// my data is here}\r\n----------------------------524246740682154737031830--\r\n",
    "type": "entity.parse.failed"
  }
}

My code
In the body of request I have to send something like this
{
  proposalData: {
    id_quotation_proposal: Int;
    id_vehicle: Int;
    id_address: Int;
    renavam: string;
    billingType: string;
    comission: float;
    value: float;
    client: {
      name: string;
      cpf: string;
      phone: string;
      email: string;
      gender: Int;
      birthdate: string;
    };
    creditCard: {}; // not required
  };
  vehicleInvoice: Buffer;// not required
  vehicleDocument: Buffer;// not required
}

The docs says I have to send the body as a FormData and the proposalData as a serialized object.
Preparing data:
const body = await req.json();
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('proposalData', JSON.stringify(body.proposalData));

Axios request:
const response = await axios.post(url, formData, { 
  headers: { Authorization: token, }, 
});

I tried this:
const response = await axios.post( url, formData, { 
  headers: { 
    Authorization: token,
    ...formData.getHeaders() 
  },
});

and this
headers: { 
  Authorization: token, 
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
},

PS.: When I use insomnia to request, it works.
Update: I made the request using the deprecated "request-promise" and it works.
Look the code
import request from 'request-promise'
// rest of my code
try{
  const response = await request({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: url,
    headers: {
      Authorization: token,
      ...formData.getHeaders(),
    },
    body: formData,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
  });
// rest of code


Can you add the server-side code that tries to parse the parameter?

@Barmar, I can't. It's a third part API. If you want to see the docs, it's in Portuguese, see: https://docs.splitrisk.com.br/proposta/enviar-proposta.

Can you show the value of req.json() (redact personal information like account numbers).

@Barmar, Yeah, that's an object like this:
{
"id_quotation_proposal": 1471,
"id_vehicle": 2783,
"id_address": 2754,
"renavam": "123456789456",
"billingType": "billet",
"comission": 0.0,
"value": 0.0,
"creditCard": {},
"client": {
"name": "John Due",
"cpf": "123.456.789-00",
"phone": "62999999999",
"email": "email@email.com",
"gender": 1,
"birthdate": "1990-01-01"
},
"mainDriver": {
"name": "John Due",
"cpf": "123.456.789-00",
"birthdate": "1990-01-01"
}
}

That doesn't look anything like the Client or CreditCard objects shown at the link you gave.

I don't see any mention of a data1 parameter.

@Barmar I added some new information and changed the code to explain it better.

You should only send the information from body.client, not the entire body. And there's no mention of an option1 field in the API documentation, so I think each property should be a separate field in the FormData.
const body = await req.json();
const formData = new FormData();
Object.entries(body.client).forEach(
  ([key, value]) => formData.append(key, value));

const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: token,
  },
});


Thanks for the reply.
"Option1" was just to show how I added the first field, sorry about that.
So... I will edit and add some news information.
